# count lines in multiple files and output along with file names

Tags: python, count

I wanted to get the number of lines in each file in a folder and print out the number of lines along with the file name adjacently. Having just entered the world of programming, I managed to write this short code, borrowing them from here and there.

```
#count the number of lines in all files and output both count number and file name
import glob
list_of_files = glob.glob('./*.linear')
for file_name in list_of_files:
    with open (file_name) as f, open ('countfile' , 'w') as out :
        count = sum (1 for line in f)
        print >> out, count, f.name
```

But this gives an output of only one of the file.

This could be done pretty easily using `wc -l *`.linear  in shell, but I wanted to know how to do this in python.

P.S : I sincerely hope I am not duplicating questions!

Comment: That's because you're truncating the `countfile` again and again with each iteration.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are really close! Just open the countfile once, not inside the loop:

```
import glob
with open('countfile' , 'w') as out:
    list_of_files = glob.glob('./*.linear')
    for file_name in list_of_files:
        with open(file_name, 'r') as f:
            count = sum(1 for line in f)
            out.write('{c} {f}\n'.format(c = count, f = file_name))
```

Every time a file is opened in `w` mode, (e.g. `open('countfile', 'w')`), the contents of `countfile` (if it already exists) is deleted. That is why you need to only call it once.

Comment: Kudos for replacing the `print >> ...` stuff.  I never liked that form of `print`.  It just doesn't seem to fit with the rest of python's syntax.

Comment: @mgilson: Yes, I never use `print out >>`. And `print` is a function in Python3 so there is little point in using it now. :)

Comment: It is slightly different than `file.write`.  It implicitly calls `str` on the items passed to it, and it automagically appends a newline (unless you have a trailing comma of course).  That said, I'd still rather use string formatting or interpolation.